# vscode code gdb, how to halt, not stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In VS Code V1.73.1 - I am running GDB (actually a RISCV variant, debugging a target board vi jtag).

I"m also quite a bit confused and do not know if this is a VSCODE problem or a plugin problem, and there are multiple plugins involved,

If it is a plugin then I'm thinking it is the one that controls GDB... and other things are built upon that plugin. But - GDB is so much at the core that I think that the GDB component is actually part of the baseline VS-CODE package.

Background: I want to halt the cpu I am debugging so that i can inspect global variables and/or set breakpoints. I cannot seem to do that.

I normally go through the connect, load, then type continue. If I set a breakpoint before I type continue - it works.

My code is now running, I want to stop - add a breakpoint and continue.

To be clear - I do not mean disconnect and stop debugging, I want to stop or halt the cpu at its current location.

The normal method or action for GDB is to type Control_C in the GDB terminal but - this is VS Code, its not a normal terminal.

The question is how do I stop or halt the cpu under control of the debugger

Its not obvious, and no menu seems to find that selection.

if it was an local debug session I could do something like controlC in a console window or use KILL to send a signal, but - this is an embedded/remote GDB session so that is not possible.